# How to pass/map Date object from JavaScript to DateTime object in C# MVC controller action through ajax post?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am **posting** a **JavaScript date object** from the client side and receiving it in the C# controller action. In the C# controller action the object is mapped to a C# **`DateTime` object**.

But the DateTime object is not getting the exact value from javascript date object.

Its showing DateTime's *min value*, i.e.

> 01-01-0001 12:00:00 AM

Here is my script code:

```
var laraHistory = {
        HistoryId: historyId,
        CompanyId: companyId,
        ChangedDate: new Date(Date.parse(changedDate)), //here is how i am setting the date
        LaraId: laraId,
        Comments: comments,
        ChangedById: changedById,
        IsDeleted: true
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Manage/HideLaraHistory",
        data: JSON.stringify({ companyLaraHistory: laraHistory }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
```

- Here is my client side breakpoint screen-shot:

[image]

- Here is my C# controller action screen-shot:

[image]

Here is my ViewModel class:

```
public class CompanyLaraHistoryViewModel
{
    public int HistoryId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "LARA")]
    public byte LaraId { get; set; }
    public LARA Lara { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Changed Date")]
    public DateTime ChangedDate { get; set; }
    public int ChangedById { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Comments")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

What can be the possible reason for this? Is it that js date objects cannot be mapped to c# datetime objects?

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: How are you posting the value? Show the relevant part of your script where you set the value. And what is the culture on the server?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated my question with the script..

Comment: @Utsav Dawn You can either use the browser dev tools or Fiddler to see the request body and determine if it is same value being passed. IMO it could be a case sensitive typo.

Comment: @kanchirk no my case is ok..no typos there..

Comment: Check `Request.Form` to what the actual value you are receiving, and check that it can be parsed to `DateeTime` based on the server culture

Comment: @StephenMuecke how to do that? can you tell me the process?

Comment: Can you first see if `ChangedDate: (new Date(Date.parse(changedDate))).toISOString(),` is correctly bound

Comment: There is no change with .toISOString()...

Comment: @UtsavDawn, Just try hard coding a simple date in ISO format. i.e `ChangedDate: '2015-05-10',` to make sure you have no issues server side

Comment: Its still the same after hardcoding also..

Answer (score 0):

Consider different approach to the problem. In my applications i prefer to 
send dates or time to server in some constant format.

For example if in JS I have date which is 1-st January 2015, I send it to server in following format YYYY-MM-DD, and then on server I parse it it C#/any_other_language Date object.

It requires using an Client-Server Adapter which is aware of this format. The same I do when I get date from server. I have an Adapter which converts string to JS Date object.

Comment: do you pass the date as a string from client to server or as a Date object?

Comment: I pass it as a String, and the on Server I have parser which converts it to Date.

Comment: As a bonus when my app is requested via standard GET link, I have one mechanism to convert date, because no matter whether it is a JSON request to API or GET request for page I have one format for dates

Comment: So tell me one thing can I pass it as a Date object from js and map it to a DateTime object in c#?

Comment: @djaszczurowski, Sorry but this is nonsense. Form data is simply a collection  of name/value pairs. There is no such this as `string` of `DateTime` of a javascript `Date` object. If the 'date' value is in a correct format, the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind it.

Comment: Again, lets say you have (in JS), Date refering to 1st January 2015,


Then I would intialize `laraHistory` variable in that manner:

`var laraHistory = {
        HistoryId: historyId,
        CompanyId: companyId,
        ChangedDate: ClientServerAdapter.adaptDate(changedDate)
        LaraId: laraId,
        Comments: comments,
        ChangedById: changedById,
        IsDeleted: true
    };`

Now you are sending `ChangedDate` attribute of `laraHistory` as a String in your expected format

Comment: What is crucial here is the `format` word. 

I always pass Date/Time to server in the same format no matter what is the source of the request.

Comment: @StephenMuecke 

I agree with what you wrote - `if the 'date' is in a correct format`. What I enforce thanks to Adapters, is that I always get the `correct format`, Nothing more, nothing less.  That's my point.

Comment: @djaszczurowski. You have indicated _"It requires using an Client-Server Adapter"_. If the format is ISO format, then the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind it. However using `.toISOString()` on  a jascript `Date` object, or just hardcoding a value such as '2015-05-10` will work correctly but OP claims it does not, so his problem is elsewhere anyway